# Difference between USE dbName VS dbName.TableName?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between:

```sql
USE SchoolDB;
SELECT * FROM  StudentTable;
```

vs.

```sql
SELECT * FROM SchoolDB.dbo.StudentTable;
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both of these? Is there any affect on query performance?

I have searched almost everywhere, I could not find any resource. if there is any duplicate question or link it would be really helpful.
The only thing I found out in Microsoft SQL Management Studio was `USE` keyword keeps the connection open to DB where as `dbName.TableName` does not.

Comment: The first one changes the context for all queries that follow. Your last sentence is wrong though, `USE` doesn't keep the connection open.

Comment: `USE` changes the database you are connected to; referencing a object by using 3 part naming does not.

Comment: Also, your 2 queries aren't the same. The first would query the table `StudentTable`, in the database `SchoolDB` on the user's default schema for that database (`dbo`?). The second would query the table `StudentTable`, on the **schema** `SchoolDB` on the currently connected database (`master` maybe?).

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies. i really appreciate, now i can sleep peacefully.

Comment: @DavidG to reproduce the connection open problem, Server Managment Studio -> New Query -> Create a TestDB  and TestTable ->write a simple query using the 'USE' keyword, -> execute -> Delete the TestDB (Make sure to untick the close existing connection checkbox in bottom) - > it throws an Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of both of these? Is there any affect on query performance?

**Use DBName**

- Switches default database context, so that you do not have to write Three-part-name in your query

**Multi-part Names**

- Helpful when your script targets multiple database, within same query (Select, Delete, Update etc..)
- To eliminate name resolution errors specially when you query targets multiple databases. even though, if your query does't target multiple databases it always best practice mention objects with two-part name i.e. `dbo.table`

In summary, there is no impact on performance using either method, but as mentioned above there is possibility of syntax error while NOT using [Multi-part names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, "Use" creates a context so all subsequent queries execute against that database; three-part-name explicitly name the database. There's no performance impact in this choice.

But there are design choices you might make which impact your decision.

For instance, you may have development, test and production databases. If you have a SQL batch file (for instance), it's probably better to explicitly set the database context and then execute the query without the three-part-name.

You may have an application design which splits data across different databases (customer, product, sales, for instance); in that case, it may be easier to agree to use the three-part-name style, so your queries can execute in any one of the databases.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing i found out was ... 'USE' keyword keeps the connection
>   open to db

...no, it's nothing to do with connections.

`USE` simply sets a database as a default *context*. It means that any future commands (until the next `USE` statement) where an object is named but no database name is specified by a prefix will be assumed to belong to the database specified in the `USE` statement.

e.g.

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT * FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.SomeOtherTable
SELECT * FROM MyView
USE AThirdDatabase
SELECT * FROM AThirdTable
```

In the above set of commands, the statements on lines 2 and 4 will be treated as referring to objects in `MyDatabase` because of the `USE` command. (It also, separately assumes the default `dbo` schema since that is unspecified as well).

Line 3 names a database specifically, by contrast. This is a one-off and does not change the context defined by `USE`

And after the second `USE` command, the statement on line 6 will be assumed to refer to an object in `AThirdDatabase`.

---

P.S. The example code in your question isn't quite representative of the issue you're asking about - you haven't taken schemas into account.

Your first query would select from `StudentTable`, on the default schema (usually `dbo`) in `SchoolDB`. That's fine. But in the second query `SchoolDB` would be assumed to be the schema name, not the database name. SQL would assume a connection to the default database (usually `master` unless the logged in user has a different one configured).

`dbName.TableName` (as per your title) is not a valid structure for an object name - if you specify the database then you have to specify the schema as well (otherwise the reference could be ambiguous between two objects in different schemas with the same name).